# ASP.NET MVC, Querystring, routes and default binder, how do I combine this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, strongly-typed-view, request.querystring

I have an ASP.NET MVC site that uses strongly typed views. In my case, a controller action could look like this:

```
public ActionResult List(MyStrongType data)
```

When submitting the page (view) the response will generate a URL that looks something like this (yes, I know routing could generate a nicer URL):

```
http://localhost/Ad/List?F.ShowF=0&ALS.CP=30&ALS.L=0&ALS.OB=0&ALS.ST=0&S=&LS.L1=&LS.L2=&CS.C1=32&CS.C2=34&CS.C3=&ALS.ST=0
```

If I submit the page again, I can see that the data object in the action is set properly (according to the URL)(default binder).

The problem is: Say that I am to add page buttons (to change the page) for a list on my sitepage, the list will be controlled by settings like filter, sortorder, amount of pages per page and so on (controlled by the querystring). First, I need to include all current query parameters in the URL, and then I need to update the page parameter without tampering with the other query parameters. How can I genereate this URL from the view/"HTML helper"?

I could of course manipulate the URL string manually, but this will involve a lot of work and it will be hard to keep up to date if a route is changed, there must be a easier way? Like some kind of querystring collection that can be altered on service side (like ASP.NET Request.QueryString)?

I would hope to not involve the route, but I post the one I got so far anyway:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "TreeEditing",
        "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}",
        new { controller = "MyCategory", action = "Add", name = string.Empty, id = -1 }
    );
```

**BestRegards**

Edit 1: It's possible to set the query parameters like this (in view):

```
<%= url.Action(new {controller="search", action="result", query="Beverages", Page=2})%>
```

But this will only generate a URL like this (with the default route):

```
/search/result?query=Beverages&page=2
```

The rest of the parameters will be missing as you can see.

I could of course add every known parameter in this [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) action, but if any query parameter is added or changed there will be a lot of work to keep everything up to date.

I have read the article *[ASP.NET MVC Framework (Part 2): URL Routing](http://aspalliance.com/1525_ASPNET_MVC_Framework_Part_2_URL_Routing.all)*, but how do I find an answer to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like the problem you have is that you want to be able to easily persist query string values from the current request and render them into the URLs of links in your view.  One solution would be to create an HtmlHelper method that returns the existing query string with some changes.  I created an extension method for the HtmlHelper class that takes an object and merges its property names and values with the query string from the current request, and returns the modified querystring.  It looks like this:

```
public static class StackOverflowExtensions
{
    public static string UpdateCurrentQueryString(this HtmlHelper helper, object parameters)
    {
        var newQueryStringNameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString);
        foreach (var propertyInfo in parameters.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            newQueryStringNameValueCollection[propertyInfo.Name] = propertyInfo.GetValue(parameters, null).ToString();
        }

        return ToQueryString(newQueryStringNameValueCollection);
    }

    private static string ToQueryString(NameValueCollection nvc)
    {
        return "?" + string.Join("&", Array.ConvertAll(nvc.AllKeys, key => string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nvc[key]))));
    }
}
```

It will loop through the query string values from the current request and merge in the properties defined on the object you passed in.  So your view code might look like this:

```
<a href='/SomeController/SomeAction<%=Html.GetCurrentQueryStringWithReplacements(new {page = "2", parameter2 = "someValue"})%>'>Some Link</a>
```

This is basically saying "keep the query string from the current request, but change the page and parameter2 values, or create them if they didn't exist."  Note that if your current request has a "page" query string parameter, this method will overwrite the value from the current request with the one you explicitly pass in from the view.
In this case, if your querystring was:

```
?parameter1=abc&page=1
```

It would become:

```
?parameter1=abc&page=2&parameter2=someValue
```

**EDIT:**
The above implementation will probably not work with the dictionary lookup of querystring parameter names you described.  Here is an implementation and that uses a dictionary instead of an object:

```
    public static string UpdateCurrentQueryString(this HtmlHelper helper, Dictionary<string, string> newParameters)
    {
        var newQueryStringNameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString);
        foreach (var parameter in newParameters)
        {
            newQueryStringNameValueCollection[parameter.Key] = parameter.Value;
        }

        return ToQueryString(newQueryStringNameValueCollection);
    }
```

Your view would call the function by doing an inline initialization of a dictionary and passing it to the helper function like this:

```
<a href='/SomeController/SomeAction<%=Html.GetCurrentQueryStringWithReplacements(new Dictionary<string,string>() {
{ QuerystringHandler.Instance.KnownQueryParameters[QuaryParameters.PageNr], "2" },
{ QuerystringHandler.Instance.KnownQueryParameters[QuaryParameters.AnotherParam], "1234" }})%>'>Some Link</a>
```

Comment: > This looks vary good, I have built a similar solution but not that fancy ;) There is however a qustion, in my case I am storing the query parameter in a shared place so to know how the page parameter looks like I will run : QuerystringHandler.Instance.KnownQueryParameters[QuaryParameters.PageNr] In this case the return value will be "Page". Is it possible to combine this with your solution?

Comment: You may have to post some of your code, I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: > Sorry. A querystring contains query parameter right. A quary parameter might look like this Page=20. If the query parameter Page is used in many places it will be some work if this query parameter should change name. So instead I am storing known query parameter in a dicationary like this Dicationare<queryParamKey, string>. the queryParamKey is enum. By writing this Dictionary[queryParamKey] I will get "Page" in this case. Do get it? I stores queryParameters that is used at manyplaces in a Dictionary to be able to change name easy(one place). This does not work in your solution.

Comment: @SnowJim I added some code that I think will work with you're trying to do.  I created another implementation of the helper method that takes a dictionary, which should allow you to make use of your helper class that returns parameter names.  The view code gets a little longer because dictionary initialization is a little more verbose than creating an anonymous object.

Answer (score 2):

I did JUST what you need!

I created an HTML helper for this. The helper takes the same parameters as a normal helper. Yet, it keeps the current values from the URL. I made it both for the `URL helper` as a `ActionLink helper`.

This replaces the: `Url.Action()`

```
<a href='<%= Html.UrlwParams("TeamStart","Inschrijvingen", new {modID=item.Mod_ID}) %>'  title="Selecteer">
    <img src="<%= Url.Content("~/img/arrow_right.png") %>" alt="Selecteer" width="16" /></a>
```

and this replaces the `Html.ActionLink()`

```
<%: Html.ActionLinkwParams("Tekst of url", "Action", new {test="yes"}) %>
```

Here is the helper:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace MVC2_NASTEST.Helpers {
    public static class ActionLinkwParamsExtensions {
        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkwParams(this HtmlHelper helper, string linktext, string action, string controller, object extraRVs, object htmlAttributes) {

            NameValueCollection c = helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

            RouteValueDictionary r = new RouteValueDictionary();
            foreach (string s in c.AllKeys) {
                r.Add(s, c[s]);
            }

            RouteValueDictionary htmlAtts = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

            RouteValueDictionary extra = new RouteValueDictionary(extraRVs);

            RouteValueDictionary m = RouteValues.MergeRouteValues(r, extra);

            //return System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(helper, linktext, action, controller, m, htmlAtts);
            return helper.ActionLink(linktext, action, controller, m, htmlAtts);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkwParams(this HtmlHelper helper, string linktext, string action) {
            return ActionLinkwParams(helper, linktext, action, null, null, null);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkwParams(this HtmlHelper helper, string linktext, string action, string controller) {
            return ActionLinkwParams(helper, linktext, action, controller, null, null);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkwParams(this HtmlHelper helper, string linktext, string action, object extraRVs) {
            return ActionLinkwParams(helper, linktext, action, null, extraRVs, null);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkwParams(this HtmlHelper helper, string linktext, string action, string controller, object extraRVs) {
            return ActionLinkwParams(helper, linktext, action, controller, extraRVs, null);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkwParams(this HtmlHelper helper, string linktext, string action, object extraRVs, object htmlAttributes) {
            return ActionLinkwParams(helper, linktext, action, null, extraRVs, htmlAttributes);
        }
    }

    public static class UrlwParamsExtensions {
        public static string UrlwParams(this HtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller, object extraRVs) {
            NameValueCollection c = helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

            RouteValueDictionary r = RouteValues.optionalParamters(c);

            RouteValueDictionary extra = new RouteValueDictionary(extraRVs);

            RouteValueDictionary m = RouteValues.MergeRouteValues(r, extra);

            string s = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl("", action, controller, m, helper.RouteCollection, helper.ViewContext.RequestContext, false);
            return s;
        }

        public static string UrlwParams(this HtmlHelper helper, string action) {
            return UrlwParams(helper, action, null, null);
        }

        public static string UrlwParams(this HtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller) {
            return UrlwParams(helper, action, controller, null);
        }

        public static string UrlwParams(this HtmlHelper helper, string action, object extraRVs) {
            return UrlwParams(helper, action, null, extraRVs);
        }
    }
}
```

**How does it work?**

The calls are the same as for the `Html.ActionLink()` so you simple can replace those.

The method does the following:

It takes all the optional parameters from the current URL and places them in a `RouteValueDictionary`.
It also places the `htmlattributes` in a dictionary.
Then it takes the extra routevalues which you specified manually and places those in a `RouteValueDictionary` as well.

The key then is to merge the ones from the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) and the ones manually specified.

This happens in the RouteValues class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVC2_NASTEST {
    public static class RouteValues {

        public static RouteValueDictionary optionalParamters() {
            return optionalParamters(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString);
        }

        public static RouteValueDictionary optionalParamters(NameValueCollection c) {
            RouteValueDictionary r = new RouteValueDictionary();
            foreach (string s in c.AllKeys) {
                r.Add(s, c[s]);
            }
            return r;
        }

        public static RouteValueDictionary MergeRouteValues(this RouteValueDictionary original, RouteValueDictionary newVals) {
            // Create a new dictionary containing implicit and auto-generated values
            RouteValueDictionary merged = new RouteValueDictionary(original);

            foreach (var f in newVals) {
                if (merged.ContainsKey(f.Key)) {
                    merged[f.Key] = f.Value;
                } else {
                    merged.Add(f.Key, f.Value);
                }
            }
            return merged;
        }

        public static RouteValueDictionary MergeRouteValues(this RouteValueDictionary original, object newVals) {
            return MergeRouteValues(original, new RouteValueDictionary(newVals));
        }
    }
}
```

This is all pretty straightforward. In the end, the `actionlink` is made with the merged routevalues. This code also lets you remove values from the URL.

**Examples:**

Your URL is `localhost.com/controller/action?id=10&foo=bar`. If in that page you place this code

```
 <%: Html.ActionLinkwParams("Tekst of url", "Action", new {test="yes"}) %>
```

the URL returned in that element will be `localhost.com/controller/action?id=10&foo=bar&test=yes`.

If you want to remove an item, you just set the item as an empty string. For example,

```
 <%: Html.ActionLinkwParams("Tekst of url", "Action", new {test="yes", foo=""}) %>
```

will return the URL in the <a> element: `localhost.com/controller/action?id=10&test=yes`

I'm guessing this is all you need?

If you have some additional questions, just ask.

**Extra:**

Sometimes you will want to keep your values inside your action too, when you will redirect to another Action. With my RouteValues class, this can be done very easily:

```
 public ActionResult Action(string something, int? somethingelse) {
                    return RedirectToAction("index", routeValues.optionalParamters(Request.QueryString));
 }
```

If you still want to add some optional parameters, no problem!

```
 public ActionResult Action(string something, int? somethingelse) {
                    return RedirectToAction("index", routeValues.optionalParamters(Request.QueryString).MergeRouteValues(new{somethingelse=somethingelse}));
 }
```

I think that covers pretty much everything you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the query string in a link of a view:

```
Html.ActionLink("LinkName", "Action", "Controller", new { param1 = value1, param2 = value2 }, ...)
```

If you want to set it in the browser [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) after a post back, just call Route* in an **action** like `RouteToAction()` and set the parameter key/value you want.

Comment: But what if the url already contains a couple of querystring parameters that I need to include in the url? I know which parameters that exists but I do not know which one that is uncludede in the url. Is it possible to set this from a helper?

Answer (score 0):

- If you use the action `public ActionResult List(MyStrongType data)`, you need to include all page settings (page index, ordering,...) as parameters to 'MyStrongType', and the data object will contain all infomation for the view.
- In the view, if you need to generate a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), using the approach of CallMeLaNN:
  `Html.ActionLink("LinkName", "Action", "Controller", new { param1 = Model.value1, param2 = Model.param2, ... });`. You need to manually set all the parameters here or create a helper to help you fill the URL.
- You don't need to care about current parameters included in the address.
- You can route:
  routes.MapRoute(
      "custome",
      "{controller}/{action}/",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
  );
  to generate all the parameters as a query string.